# There have some error in this code regarding <div> i think

Tags: html, css

I want to write their name and position inside the box and i tried everything to do this like pic dimension, height-width size of div, but It didn't work. So, please guide me how can I make this as shown in pic 1.

This is what I want to create:

[image: This is what I want to create]

This is what I created:

[This is what I created.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVhvW.png)

```css
.card{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px black;
    transition: 1s;
}
.desc{
    
    padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
.card:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg" alt="man">
        <div class="desc">
            <h3>Rahul Kumar</h3>
            <p>Data Analyst</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg" alt="woman">
        <div class="desc">
            <h3>Neha Sharma</h3>
            <p>Software Engineer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `height` on a container is almost always wrong, so the solution here is just to remove it:

```css
.card {
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px black;
  transition: 1s;
}

.desc {
  padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg" alt="man">
  <div class="desc">
    <h3>Rahul Kumar</h3>
    <p>Data Analyst</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg" alt="woman">
  <div class="desc">
    <h3>Neha Sharma</h3>
    <p>Software Engineer</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This can result in the problem, that you don't have equal height elements, but that can be easily solved with `flex`. And what you should also always do is to include the actual size of the image in the HTML, so that you won't get layout shifts when the image is loaded.

```css
.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px black;
  transition: 1s;
}

.desc {
  padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg" alt="man" width="200" height="200">
    <div class="desc">
      <h3>Rahul Kumar</h3>
      <p>Data Analyst</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg" alt="woman"  width="200" height="200">
    <div class="desc">
      <h3>Neha Sharma</h3>
      <p>Software Engineer<br>some<br>more<br>lines</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the card height value from 200px to 100%

```css
.card{
    width: 200px;
    height:100%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px black;
    transition: 1s;
}
.desc{
    
    padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
.card:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg" alt="man">
        <div class="desc">
            <h3>Rahul Kumar</h3>
            <p>Data Analyst</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg" alt="woman">
        <div class="desc">
            <h3>Neha Sharma</h3>
            <p>Software Engineer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```